# Typescript execute code after nested for loop is completed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, synchronization

I have a nested for loop and internal loop also makes service calls in angular 2

```
public populateData: any[] = [];

let appCounter = 0;
this.list.forEach(data => {       <---- outer loop
    this.service.getSubs(data.id).subscribe(res => { <---- backend call to get data
            let subscriptions = res.subscriptions;

            subscriptions.forEach(subscription => {
                if(condition){
                    this.populateData.push(subscription);   
                }
            });     
    }); 
    appCounter++;
    if(appCounter == this.list.length){
        console.log('--------- subscriptionList ----------');
        console.log(this.populateData);
    }
});
```

I want to call a method after `populateData` variable is populated by executing outer loop completely.

currently, it gives me empty array in the console, because outer loop executes completely while inner HTTP calls are still pending.

Comment: seems that `promises` are here for you, more precisely `Promise.all`. Or you can do it the old school way by incrementing a variable inside the callback and test if all responses arrived, so you can trigger the rest of the code (all this inside the callback, except the var that needs not to loose its value between steps)

Comment: if i print `appCounter` variable in `getSubs` service call, it prints value equal to size of `this.list`, because even for first service call outer loop is executed and `appCounter` is incremented.

Comment: the counter increment and the test of its value must be inside the async call's callback for this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have some luck with [**forkJoin**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';

public populateData: any[] = [];
public observables: any[] = [];

this.list.forEach(data => { 
  this.observables.push(this.service.getSubs(data.id)); 
});

Observable.forkJoin(this.observables)
  .subscribe(res => {
    res.forEach((element:any) => {
      let subscriptions = element.subscriptions;
      subscriptions.forEach(subscription => {
        if(condition){
          this.populateData.push(subscription);   
        }
      });
      console.group('subscription list');
      console.log(this.populateData);
    });
  })
```

Comment: Tried this but i am getting `'subscriptions' does not exist on type '{}'`, if i do `console.log(element)` data is there but there is icon `i` in console that says `Values below are just evaluated now`

Comment: try changing `res.forEach(element...` to `res.forEach((element:any)...`

Comment: subscriptions are coming after this change, is there a way to get `data` variable in `res.forEach((element..`

Comment: i found a workaround to get `data` in object in `res.forEach`. Thanks for solution